# Who was the first to show that there is a Universal Turing-Machine that uses a binary alphabet?

Tags: math-history, computability, turing-machines

The title says it all, I think.

We know there are universal Turing-machines that only use a binary alphabet.  But who proved this first?

Turing himself showed the existence of a universal Turing machine ... but did he also show that such a machine can exist using only a binary alphabet? Or was that someone else?

Or was it just 'obvious' to him and others that this would be the case, and hence no explicit 'first' proof or publication of this result exists?

But if there is a publication that can be considered the 'first' proof of this result, I would be very interested in knowing what that is.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibile sources, EF Moore, [A simplified UTM](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/62f0/b0e6852978d1aee47008fd621a34f1d7725a.pdf) (1952) as well as [Hao Wang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hao_Wang_(academic)), [A Variant to Turing's Theory of Computing Machines](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320867) (1957).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - In the Moore paper, the first complete paragraph on page 52 explains why a binary alphabet is sufficient (and I expect that  most researchers would have known this).

Comment: When I get my Ph.D in philosophy, I will probably be able to answer this question. But for now (as a freshman) I cant even understand your question. Is it really normal that I cannot understand it, maybe I will change my major. hahahaa

Comment: @sallyhappy Yes, it's quite normal for a freshman not to follow this :)  But keep working on logic, and take some introductory course on computability (probably some kind of 'foundations in computer science' course will do) and you'll start to see the very deep connections between logic, computation, and mathematics.  There are a number of books out there as well that try to cover this material in 'laymen's terms. I personally like "Engines of Logic" by Martin Davis.  Just a couple of bucks on Amazon!

Comment: Ok, I will check that ("Engines of Logic" by Martin Davis) out. Thank you for the advice :) I appreciaaaate it :)

Answer (score 0):

A Turing machine where a tape cell has only two possible symbols is sometimes called a [Post machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%E2%80%93Turing_machine). Post's model was actually developed independently of Turing's and published later the same year, in 1936; but I think it must have been clear to both of them, and to those who saw both papers, that the two are equivalent.